# conditional probability to refill automated coffemachine

Tags: probability

Given is a fully automated coffeemaker which has to be filled with water and coffee beans when empty, and a container with coffee dregs which has to get empty when full.

Now there is a group of people with different coffee consume. For example:

Albert drinks about 2 coffees a day; Jessica drinks 5 coffees a day and Marc, who drinks 6

When taking a coffee, the machine can either need a refilling before the coffee can be made, after the coffee is made, or neither (lucky hit).

Everyone can ignore it, when the machine is empty afterward, but no one can ignore it if the refill has to be done before the coffee is made, because they won't get a coffee without refilling before.

The Question:

There could be either a rule that says "If you made a coffee and the machine needs something afterward, refill!" or no rule.

Does the probability to refill the machine differ, depending on the rule and will one of the two scenarios be unfair to those who drink more or less coffee?

Comment: Probability of what ??

Comment: to refill the machine ! !

Comment: This question needs a lot more specifics. It's currently not clear in what sense the refilling of the machine is a probabilistic event, in which order the coffee consumers arrive (in regular intervals? randomly? with which distribution?), how "refilling the machine" relates to the three required actions listed in the first paragraph, whether the three options listed in the fourth paragraph are to be interpreted probabilistically, if so, with which distribution, etc.

Comment: Is this from a book or have you made it up ?

Comment: This has been a discussion under coworker. Is it answerable with this amount of information?

Comment: Absolutely not !! See joriki's comment.

Comment: Only reliable rule: If machine is empty, the person most desperate for coffee will eventually tend to it. Usual rules of honor and decency do not seem to apply to coffee or other addictions. Theoretical solution among (imaginary) people who would follow the rules, as proposed by @joriki might be fun to formulate and solve.